# Variable function names in Require & Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using Require.js and Backbone, and have a Backbone router module like:

```
define([
  "views/global",
  "views/project/edit",
  "views/project/list",
], function(GlobalView, edit, list){
    return Backbone.Router.extend({

      routes: {
        "projects/:action/" : "projectsAction",
      },

      projectsAction : function(action) {
        /* .... lots of code cut out here .... */
        /* Create and render the action specified */
        this.subView = new eval(action+"()").render();

      }
  });
});
```

This is an example, I've cut a lot of setup code out of projectAction.
I would like the URL: `/projects/list` to run projectAction, with the `action` param = `list`, and then the `list` module from the Require.js function to be called.  I'm currently doing it with `eval()`, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Basically, in Javascript, can you refer to a variable, with another variable name, without using `eval()`?

I guess a shorter version would be, how do you do:

```
var name = "Math.random";
name();  // = 0.34343....
```

Without `eval()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access a variable having the name in a string. But you can create a mapping:

```
var actions = {
    edit: edit,
    list: list
};
```

And then you can access the function by the key:

```
projectsAction : function(action) {
    this.subView = new actions[action]().render();
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks, that looks like the closest thing to what I asked.  Although with hindsight my question was ambiguous, so there is a better way (see below), to what I was actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The best way imo, is to use the `require` function of requirejs:

```
projectsAction : function(action) {
    /* .... lots of code cut out here .... */
    /* Create and render the action specified */
    var self = this;
    require('views/project/' + action, function(view) {
      (self.subView = new view).render();
    }
  }
```

As it would also cut the boilerplate from having lots of actions.

Comment: Ah that's brilliant!  I'm new to require, I didn't know you could do that.  As you said, it greatly simplifies all the boilerplate as well.  I'm going to mark the other answer as correct because it was the closest answer to what I actually asked (with hindsight my question was ambiguous), but this is really helpful, thanks.