# How to Load backbone views from modules using RequireJS?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

```
define(['jquery','frameworkviews/BackbonePrototype','applicationPath/Module1/js/views/AppView1','applicationPath/Module2/js/views/AppView2'],   
function($,BackbonePrototype,AppView1,AppView2){
  function getViews(modules,type){
    var views= new Array();
    for ( var i = 0; i < modules.length; ++i) {
      var cmd = 'views[' + i + '] = new ' + modules[i]+'View.'+modules[i]+type + "View" + '() ;';
      eval(cmd);
      views[i].name = modules[i];
    }
    return views;
  }
});
```

---

We are developing a project with backbone and RequireJS. Our project is based on framework and modules architecture. The modules contribute 
backbone views ( AppView1/AppView2 etc) and are dynamically loaded by the Framework using RequireJS as shown above.The problem we are facing is that 
if a new module is added (e.g. Module3) then again the above framework code needs to be modified to add the Module3 views to the define block. 
Is there any way to avoid such changes in the framework and how to obtain reference to that newly added module view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use eval. That's evil (no pun intended).
I'll assume this is not your real code, as you're not returning anything here.

About your problem, I think you'll find everything you need here: [Variable function names in Require & Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881811/variable-function-names-in-require-backbone).

Either solutions will suit you.